# How to sign a quickbooks online API request in ColdFusion 9?

Tags: oauth, coldfusion, http-headers, coldfusion-9, quickbooks-online

In my CF app, I've used the [CF OAuth code at riaforge](http://oauth.riaforge.org/) to get request token and access token from QuickBooks Online and it works fine.
After I tried to make a QBO API call by starting to build the http headers of the call (I followed the instructions on the section "HTTP Authorization Header" here: [Implement OAuth in Your App](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0020_connect/0010_from_within_your_app/implement_oauth_in_your_app)). Then built the http header based on the methods of the code at riaforge because it worked. In addition, *I've respected the order of the parameters given by Intuit* in the previous link).

When I launched the API Call, I received the response: "signature_invalid"

I really want directions on how to sign the QBO online API Call with CF 9 if I have ready the 6 header parameters:

- oauth_token
- oauth_nonce
- oauth_consumer_key
- oauth_signature_method
- oauth_timestamp
- oauth_version

(But if possible a working code would be better)

Thank you in advance for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

this is what I use for generating the signature and header for the request token, simple additions are used for the other signatures you'll need along the way.

```
paramsStr = "oauth_callback=" & encodeData(CALL_BACK_URL) & "&" & "oauth_consumer_key=" & sConsumerKey & "&" & "oauth_nonce=" & session.nonce & "&" & "oauth_signature_method=" & SIGNMETHOD & "&" & "oauth_timestamp=" & TIMESTAMP & "&" & "oauth_version=" & VERSION;

signStr = "POST&" & encodeData(REQUEST_TOKEN_URL) & "&" & encodeData(paramsStr);

signature = computeHMACSignature(signStr, sConsumerSecret & "&");

authHeader = 'OAuth ' & createHeaderElement("oauth_consumer_key", trim(sConsumerKey)) & ", " & createHeaderElement("oauth_nonce", trim(session.nonce)) & ","  & createHeaderElement("oauth_signature_method", trim(signmethod)) & ", " & createHeaderElement("oauth_signature", trim(signature)) & ", " & createHeaderElement("oauth_timestamp", trim(TIMESTAMP)) & ", " & createHeaderElement("oauth_version", trim(VERSION)) & ", " & createHeaderElement("oauth_callback", trim(CALL_BACK_URL));
```

Comment: Tip, you can use the code button ie `{}` in the toolbar to format snippets for better readability